# jQuery show/hide with cookie

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-cookie

I've found a small jQuery cookie script so that a div at the top of my site appears when a user first hits the site; but the user can choose to close that div and their choice is remembered for a short period of time afterwards.

Now its working fine, but I want to try apply a .hide . show 'fast' to the script but changing the .css properties worked. However, if I refresh there's some bugs: it still functions as remembering my choice but the expand / collaspe fails to be in the right place.

Can anyone help? JS Code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
// LEFT COLUMN:
  // When the collapse button is clicked:
  $('.collapse').click(function() {
    $('.collapse').css("display","none");
    $('.expand').css("display","block");
    $('#actionbar').css("height","0px");
    $.cookie('actionbar', 'collapsed');
  });
  // When the expand button is clicked:
  $('.expand').click(function() {
    $('.expand').css("display","none");
    $('.collapse').css("display","block");
    $('#actionbar').css("height","70px");
    $.cookie('actionbar', 'expanded');
  });
// COOKIES
  // Left column state
  var actionbar = $.cookie('actionbar');
  // Set the user's selection for the left column
  if (actionbar == 'collapsed') {
    $('.collapse').css("display","none");
    $('.expand').css("display","block");
    $('#actionbar').css("height","0px");
  };
});
```

And my CSS:

```
.expand {
  width:11px; 
  height:11px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  left:100px;
  top:90px;
  display:none;
}
.collapse {
  width:11px; 
  height:11px;
  background:red;
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:4px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the CSS `display` property manually, you should use `.hide()` and `.show()`!

Comment: An image of the error might help to get you some more answers. If you don't yet have  the privileges post a link to one.

Comment: Have you considered doing server-side scripting?

Comment: i wouldnt kno how to go about server-side, ill look into it though, thanks for sugggesting

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of cookie'ing the classes, trying cking the event.  For instance save as expanded or collapsed, but place end page script to check for that cookie and a collapsed/expand property and then preform a click action on the coorect element?